# Using 7zip on powershell without compression

Tags: powershell, compression, 7zip

I am using 7zip on powershell because I need to zip some folders. This is the code I am using:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version "2.0"
Clear-Host
$7Zip_ProgramPath="C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z"
$Destination = "c:\temp\7ztest41.zip"
$Source = "c:\temp\homes\homeuser002"
$Option = "a"
$Command = "$7Zip_ProgramPath $Option $Destination $Source"
#$Command="C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z a c:\temp\7ztest.zip c:\temp\homes\homeuser002"
$ManagementClass=[System.Management.ManagementClass] "\\.\ROOT\cimv2:Win32_Process"
#kürzer: $$ManagementClass=[WmiClass] "Win32_Process"
$StartupOptions=[WmiClass] "Win32_ProcessStartup"
$StartupOptions.PsBase.Properties["ShowWindow"].Value=1
$null=$ManagementClass.Create($Command,$Null,$StartupOptions)'
```

I got this code from this page here: http://www.powershellpraxis.de/index.php/ntfs-filesystem/laufwerke-ordner-dateien-und-freigaben#2.1.2.5.2%20Packen%20mit%207-Zip

Everything is working quite good, except for the fact that I do not want to compress my files when using this method. I have a folder which is 67 MB big, but after zipping this folder it is only 55 MB big. Maybe I do not fully understand this code but I want to change the compression option and do not know where and how. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command line is only specifying an 'Add' operation.

```
$Option = "a"
```

The 'Add' option does not disable compression in 7z.exe.  You need to explicitly [configure the compression option](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method.htm#ZipX) to specify 'no compression'.

```
$Option = 'a -mx=0'
```

Comment: Thank you this was the option I was looking for, but I could not find the page you are refering to. I gave you the answer.

Comment: When I write it like that 7zip does not start. Is there another form of spelling possible?

Comment: Ok I got it. `$Option = 'a -mx=0` That worked for me perfectly fine.